# Numpy image - rotate matrix 270 degrees

Tags: python, matrix, image-manipulation, numpy

I've got a Numpy 2d array that represents a grey-scale image and I need to rotate it 270 degrees.  Might be being a bit thick here but the two ways I can find to do this seem quite... circulous:

```
rotated = numpy.rot90(numpy.rot90(numpy.rot90(orignumpyarray)))

rotated = numpy.fliplr(numpy.flipud(numpy.rot90(orignumpyarray)))
```

I'm thinking there must be a better way to do this in one operation.  Basically a rot270() function?  Any ideas?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can tell `rot90` to [rotate several times](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.rot90.html#numpy.rot90), this should work:

```
rotated = numpy.rot90(orignumpyarray,3)
```

Comment: rot90 also accepts negative integers so: rot90(array, -1) would also work.

Answer (score -1):

```
rotated_array =numpy.rot90(orignumpyarray,3)
```

Explanation of the function:

**numpy.rot90(a,b)**
**a =** Array which you want to rotate
**b =** How many times you want to rotate it by 90 degrees. For here you want 270° so 
90° * 3 = 270° that is why b = 3 here.